# How do I make lex/yacc match strings longer than 9000?

Tags: yacc, lex

`'[^']*\'`
I use this rule to make lex match strings, it works fine when the string length is less than 9000, so how do I get lex to match strings longer than 9,000

Whether I should change the rules? Or do I have to set something up? I wish someone could help me

Comment: I didn't find an SO answer for this already so I added mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change states from the predefined `INITIAL` state to some other state, `SQSTR`, when you encounter `'`. Within the `SQSTR` state, you switch back to `INITIAL` when you encounter an unescaped `'`. Otherwise, you stay in `SQSTR` and append characters to the token. How you optimally manage errors and string growth wrt memory allocation is an exercise left to the reader. Multi-line strings are also straightforward. And, of course, you should recognize an obvious refactoring opportunity which should be glaring red if you try to add multi-line string support.

```
%s SQSTR
%%

%{
   char *str;
   int len;
%}

<INITIAL>' {
    str = malloc(1);
    len = 0;
    *str = 0;
    BEGIN(SQSTR);
}
<SQSTR>\\' {
    str = realloc(str, len+1);
    str[len] = '\'';
    str[len+1] = 0;
    len++;
}
<SQSTR>' {
    printf("length of str is %d. First 10 is '%.10s' and last 10 are '%s'", len, str, len>=10 ? str+len-10 : str);
    BEGIN(INITIAL);
}
<SQSTR>. {
    str = realloc(str, len+1);
    str[len] = *yytext;
    str[len+1] = 0;
    len++;
}

int yywrap () {
    return 1;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    yylex();
}

$ wc bigger
       1       5   16337 bigger

$ flex t.l && gcc -g lex.yy.c && ./a.out < bigger
length of str is 16334. First 10 is 'aaaaaaaaaa' and last 10 are 'aaaaaaaaaa'
```

Edit #1 In the original post, I mistakenly placed the more general `.` rule before the `'` rule. Silly me.

Edit #2 Add main and debugging

Comment: Sorry, I find this doesn't solve my problem, when the string has such format: 'iiiiii...iiii', and its length is more than 10000, your code can't match the whole string.

Comment: It works well! Thank you so much for your assistance.